# Не грузится Винда после сброса CMOS'a

Tags: windows, windows-7

Доброго времени суток.
Сбросил CMOS на материнке FM2A58M-DG3+ (ASRock) - перестала грузиться Windows 7: логотип появляется, анимация логотипа начинается, через несколько секунд комп перезагружается. Штатное восстановление Винды не помогло. Что делать или хотя бы в какую сторону копать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не правильно выставлены настройки в биосе, посмотрите раздел про хард и поменяйте параметры

Comment: Да, необходимо особое внимание уделить параметрам контроллера SATA. Там должно стоять "IDE"/"Compatible" или "AHCI"/"Enhanced". Если не знаете, что стояло - просто попробуйте методом тыка другую настройку. Скорее всего поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, "Совместимость IDE" помогла.